# How to link a pre loader html to index

Tags: javascript, html, css, preloader

I have designed an preloader for my site which is working perfectly. But  I  want to link it to another html page without copy the source code to it.
Means like i have named preloader page as pre=loader.html and i want to link it to index.html page directly just by giving the link of preloader.html. I want that i just give an link of pre loader in index page and pre loader work normally.

Here is the code:

```js
function myFunction() {
  myVar = setTimeout(showPage, 3000);
}
function showPage() {
  document.getElementById("loader").style.display = "none";
  document.getElementById("myDiv").style.display = "block";
}
```

```css
/* Center the loader */
#loader {
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
  top: 50%;
  z-index: 1;
  width: 150px;
  height: 150px;
  margin: -75px 0 0 -75px;
  border: 16px solid #f3f3f3;
  border-radius: 50%;
  border-top: 16px solid #3498db;
  width: 120px;
  height: 120px;
-webkit-animation: spin 2s linear infinite;
  animation: spin 2s linear infinite;

@-webkit-keyframes spin {
  100% { -webkit-transform: rotate(360deg); }
}
@keyframes spin {
  0% { transform: rotate(0deg); }
  100% { transform: rotate(360deg); }
}

/* Add animation to "page content" */
.animate-bottom {
  position: relative;
  -webkit-animation-name: animatebottom;
  -webkit-animation-duration: 1s;
  animation-name: animatebottom;
  animation-duration: 1s
}

@-webkit-keyframes animatebottom {
  from { bottom:-100px; opacity:0 } 
  to { bottom:0px; opacity:1 }
}

@keyframes animatebottom { 
  from{ bottom:-100px; opacity:0 } 
  to{ bottom:0; opacity:1 }
}

#myDiv {
  display: none;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  </head>
  <body onload="myFunction()" style="margin:0;">
    <div id="loader"></div>
    <div style="display:none;" id="myDiv" class="animate-bottom">
      <h2>Tada!</h2>
      <p>Some text in my newly loaded page..</p>
    </div>
  </body>          
</html>
```

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

create a JS file say prelaoder.js, it's content should be:

```
function appendLoader(){
document.body.prepend('<div id="loader"></div>');
}
function hideLoader(){
 document.getElementById("loader").style.display = "none";
}
```

Include the prelaoder.js in your html page as script tag's source, and then invole appendLoader and hideLoader wherever needed.